# Fetch last record for each Row number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi have written query like this:

```
select Customerid,orderDate, OrderNumber,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customerid ORDER BY orderDate) "rank"
from [order]
```

and this produce result:

[image: list customer order details]

Here I want to retrieve only latest purchase of each customer like this:

```
1   2014-04-09 00:00:00.000 543141  6
2   2014-03-04 00:00:00.000 543056  4
3   2014-01-28 00:00:00.000 542986  7
```

How to achieve this using sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select o.*
from (select Customerid,orderDate, OrderNumber,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customerid ORDER BY orderDate DESC) as seqnum
      from [order] o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```